# can't push EJS variable into array in html scripttag?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, variables, ejs

I am trying to build an array with some test coordinates to use with with OpenLayers Overlays.

This is the code:

```
var parada = [];

for(var i = 0; i < <%- coords.length%>; i++){ //First loop to fill the array

    var arr = [<%- coords[i].lon %>, <%- coords[i].lat %>]; //THIS IS THE ERROR LINE! ... says the console...
    parada.push(arr);

} 

var overlays = [];

for (i = 0; i < parada.lenght; i++) { //Second loop to build the overlays
    overlays.push(new ol.Overlay({
        position: ol.proj.fromLonLat([parada[i][0], parada[i][1]]), //With the data of the array above
        positioning: 'center-center',
        element: document.getElementById('parada' + i),
        stopEvent: false
    }));

}

for (i = 0; i<overlays.length; i++){ // Last loop to assign the overlays.
    map.addOverlay(overlays[i]);
}
```

IMPORTANT: in my app.js file, coords is defined as an array of objects (that i find({}) in mongodb).

I'm really stuck here please help!
Thank you! :DDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `i` exists in the client-side JS, not in the server-side JS.

There are all sorts of ways you could fix this, one of which would be:

```
var parada = <%- JSON.stringify(coords.map(function(pair) {
    return [pair.lon, pair.lat];
})) %>;
```

I am assuming that `lon` and `lat` are always going to be numbers, such that there isn't a risk of injection attacks.

Alternatively you could do the transformation before you call the template, keep that complexity out of the template itself.

Incidentally you've also got a typo in `lenght`.

Comment: Thanks! it seems to work :)
I put your code in the app.js file like you said.
One more thing: how can I call the variable now in the EJS? <%= %>?
<%= parada[0] %> or <%= parada[0].lon %> both don't seem to work...
Thank you so much for your help! You are awesome :D

Comment: @AlanSchwarz The variable `parada` exists only in the client-side JS, not in the server-side JS. The code inside the `<% %>` is completely separate from the code outside, it's just a coincidence that both are using JavaScript. From EJS's perspective only the code inside the `<% %>` is interpreted as code, the bits outside are just arbitrary text to squirt out. The text generated by the template is then sent to the browser (you can see it in the dev tools) and the browser then runs the generated code. The two are totally separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

Made a change so it would be easier to work with the data on the client side.

```
var lon = [];
    var lat = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < <%=lon.length%>; i++ ) {<%for(var x = 0; x < lon.length ;x++) { %> 
        lon.push(<%= lon[x] %>);
        lat.push(<%= lat[x] %>);
    <% } %>}
```

This way I build an array with EJS in the client side.

```
//Create the Overlays Array
    var overlays = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < <%=lon.length%>; i++ ) {
        overlays.push(new ol.Overlay({
            position: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon[i], lat[i] ]),
            positioning: 'center-center',
            element: document.getElementById('parada' + i),
            stopEvent: false
        }));
    }
```

And then I can simply use this array where ever I need to.

Thank for the help @skirtle , you gave me understanding about the problem ;)